# Finding all abelian groups such that there exists certain short exact sequence.

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence

I have to find all abelian groups $A$ such that there exists a short exact sequence $0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{6}\rightarrow 0$.

I have found $A=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{6}$, $A=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, $A=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{3}$, and $A=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$. I am not able to find any other, but I am also not able to prove these are the only ones.

This exercise has come up in an Algebraic Topology course, so I would like to prove it using elementary abstract algebra and not Homological Algebra.

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: class of all such extensions is given by Ext$^1(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6, \mathbb{Z}).$

Comment: Another example will be $A=\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$, where the map from $\mathbb Z$ into $A$ is given by $1 \mapsto (0,6)$.

Comment: consider the semi-direct product ${\Bbb{Z}}\rtimes({\Bbb{Z}}\times{\Bbb{Z}}_6)$

Comment: So to sum it up: $\Bbb Z$, $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z_2$, $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z_3$, $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z_6$, $D_\infty$ and $D_\infty\oplus\Bbb Z_3$. (Where $D_\infty = \Bbb Z \rtimes \Bbb Z_2$.)

Comment: @Myself: I think you mean $\mathbb{Z}^2, \mathbb{Z}^2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2, \mathbb{Z}^2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3, \mathbb{Z}^2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6, D_\infty$ and $D_\infty\oplus\Bbb Z_3$ where $D_\infty = \mathbb{Z}^2 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2.$

Comment: @Krish Absolutely. I guess was off by $\Bbb Z^4$.

Comment: The question has been edited.

Comment: If this is part of an algebraic topology class, you're probably going to need homological algebra fairly soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid using ${\rm Ext}$, I think here is a possible plan.

Given an exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, we can form the following commutative diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \mathbb{Z} @>>> \mathbb{Z}^3 @>>> \mathbb{Z}^2 @>>> 0 \\
@. @| @VVV @VV V @. \\
0 @>>> \mathbb{Z} @>>> A @>>> \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} @>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$
The idea is to present $A$ as a surjection $\mathbb{Z}^3\rightarrow A$ and compute the kernel.

You can do this by taking elements and computing maps by hand, but for clarity, we can extend the diagram to 
$$
\begin{CD}
 @. 0 @>>>0  @>>>0 @. \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VV V @. \\
0 @>>> 0 @>>> \mathbb{Z} @>>> \mathbb{Z} @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VV V @. \\
0 @>>> \mathbb{Z} @>>> \mathbb{Z}^3 @>>> \mathbb{Z}^2 @>>> 0 \\
@. @| @VVV @VV V @. \\
0 @>>> \mathbb{Z} @>>> A @>>> \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} @>>> 0\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VV V @. \\
 @. 0 @>>>0  @>>>0 @. \\
\end{CD}
$$
We now focus on the upper right square:

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z} @>>>  \mathbb{Z} \\
@VVV @VVV\\
\mathbb{Z}^3 @>>>  \mathbb{Z}^2 \\
\end{CD}
$

The right vertical map is $1\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$. Since the diagram commutes, the left vertical map is $1\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} a \\ 6 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, where $a$ is some undetermined integer.

Finally, this means $A$ is the cokernel of the exact sequence 
\begin{align*}
0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^3\rightarrow A\rightarrow 0,
\end{align*}
where $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^3$ is given by $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ 6 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$. By taking row operations, we see that $A\cong \mathbb{Z}^2\oplus \mathbb{Z}/{\rm gcd}(a,6)\mathbb{Z}$, so I think your list is complete.

Edit: To be clear, there are only 4 groups for $A$ on this list, while the Ext group is apparently order 6. This is because Ext also keeps track of the maps in the short exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$, and not just the isomorphism class of $A$.

Remark 2: Computing the kernel of $\mathbb{Z}^3\rightarrow A$ is the most technical part, but I didn't realize, as applying the 9-lemma was automatic. The proof of the 9-lemma is a diagram chase, though it is slightly easier in our case. Unfortunately, a lot of the objects in the big diagram are $\mathbb{Z}$'s, which is confusing when I can't point to things, so consider:

$$
\begin{CD}
 @. 0 @. 0  @. 0 @. \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VV V @. \\
0 @>>> A_{11} @>>> A_{12} @>>> A_{13} @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VV V @. \\
0 @>>> A_{21} @>>> A_{22} @>>> A_{23} @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VV V @. \\
0 @>>> A_{31} @>>> A_{32} @>>> A_{33} @>>> 0\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VV V @. \\
 @. 0 @. 0  @. 0 @. \\
\end{CD}
$$

Here, $A_{21}=\mathbb{Z}$, $A_{22}=\mathbb{Z}^3$, $A_{32}=\mathbb{Z}^2$, etc. What we need to determine is $A_{11}$, $A_{12}$, and $A_{13}$ (the top row).

1) $A_{11}$ is the kernel of $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$, so it is 0.

2) $A_{13}$ is the kernel of $\mathbb{Z}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/6$, so it is $\mathbb{Z}$.

3) We want $A_{12}$. There are induced maps from $A_{11}$ to $A_{12}$ and $A_{12}$ to $A_{13}$ that make the diagram commute. For example, if $a\in A_{12}$, then $a$ maps to 0 under $A_{12}\rightarrow A_{22}\rightarrow A_{23}\rightarrow A_{33}$, which means $a$ maps to ${\rm ker}(A_{23}\rightarrow A_{33})$ under $A_{12}\rightarrow A_{22}\rightarrow A_{23}$. Since $A_{13}={\rm ker}(A_{23}\rightarrow A_{33})$ this means $a$ actually maps to $A_{13}$.

4) From the comments, we also know that the map $A_{12}\rightarrow A_{13}$ is surjective. We want to show that it has no kernel. Suppose $a\in {\rm ker}(A_{12}\rightarrow A_{13})$. Then, $a$ maps to 0 under $A_{12}\rightarrow A_{22}\rightarrow A_{23}$, which means $a$ maps to ${\rm ker}(A_{22}\rightarrow A_{23})\subset A_{22}$ under $A_{12}\rightarrow A_{22}$. So, we can regard the image of $a$ in $A_{22}$ as $b$, where $b$ is an element of $A_{21}$.

5) We know that $b$ maps to 0 in $A_{31}$ as $A_{31}\rightarrow A_{32}$ is injective, and $A_{21}\rightarrow A_{31}\rightarrow A_{32}$ is the same as $A_{21}\rightarrow A_{22}\rightarrow A_{32}$, and the image of $b$ under $A_{21}\rightarrow A_{22}\rightarrow A_{32}$ is the same as the image of $a$ under $A_{12}\rightarrow A_{22}\rightarrow A_{23}$, which is 0.

6) But the kernel of $A_{31}\rightarrow A_{32}$ is 0. This means $b=0$. Since $A_{12}\rightarrow A_{22}$ is injective, $a=0$. This means $A_{12}\rightarrow A_{13}$ is a bijection, so $A_{13}=\mathbb{Z}$.

You might want to consider looking up how to prove snake lemma (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SnakeLemma.html), and then directly apply that to prove the 9-lemma, since you mentioned you're taking an algebraic topology course, which is going to use this in the future anyways.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. The only thing I don't get to understand is why can we form the first conmutative diagram (Excuse my lack of knowledge, please).

Comment: I think it's possible to just guess the maps if the diagram is written out for you, but maybe it's more helpful to have motivation. Our goal is to express $A$ in terms of generators and relations. The obvious choice is to pick one generator (say $x$) as the image of 1 under $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A$, and two generators $y,z$ that map to the generators of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/6$ under the map $A\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/6$. Then, the top row of the first diagram is $\mathbb{Z}x\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}x\oplus\mathbb{Z}y\oplus\mathbb{Z}z\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}y\oplus\mathbb{Z}z$.

Comment: It's not necessary to write out all these diagrams. You can just work with $x$, $y$, and $z$ and try to figure out all the relations between them. The method is equivalent, but it's just harder to read.

Comment: How do we know $A$ is generated by those three generators and no more?

Comment: Roughly, if you can generate the kernel and image, you can generate the whole thing. To write it out, if $g\in A$, we can first find $n_1,n_2$ such that $\phi(n_1y+n_2z)=\phi(g)$, where $\phi:A\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/6$, as $\phi(y),\phi(z)$ generate $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/6$ by assumption. This means $g-n_1y-n_2z\in {\rm ker}(\phi)$. This means there exists a multiple $n'x$ of $x$ such that $n'x=g-n_1y-n_2z$.

Comment: Thank you very much, it has been very helpful. Just to finish, where does the upper right square come from?

Comment: Yeah, this is the most technical part. Going back to the generators $x$, $y$, $z$ above, we know that $\phi(6z)=6\phi(z)=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/6$, so $6z=ax$ for some $x$. This means, without doing much work, we already got to the relation $ax+6z=0$ from above. However, we need to somehow show that there are no more relations.

Comment: I knew this from the 9-lemma (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NineLemma.html), which says that the last two rows being exact implies this first row is exact. You can get the tow row of the diagram directly by taking elements and chasing them around the diagram (it's not too bad to explain in person because you can just point to things). I have to go now, but I'll write about how to do this later.

Comment: I made an edit. I still think you can work out the relations directly between $x$, $y$ and $z$, but that requires cleverness, while learning how to diagram chase will save you from needing to be clever in the future.

Comment: Did you do the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups in your algebra class? (That they are direct sums of $\mathbb{Z}$'s and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$'s?) They way I learned it is you express your abelian group as the cokernel of some map $\mathbb{Z}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n$, take the matrix $M$ of the map, and reduce it to Smith normal form. In this case, the Smith normal form is $({\rm gcd}(6,a),0,0)$.

Comment: If you haven't seen this, the idea is to change basis. For example, if $x,y,z$ are our generators, and our relation is $ax+6y=0$, then $a((x-y)+y)+6y=a(x-y)+(6+a)y=0$. So with respect to our new basis $\{x-y,y,z\}$ the relation is now expressed as the matrix $(6, 6+a, 0)$. You can do this over and over again to basically do the Euclidean algorithm on $(6,a,0)$ to get $({\rm gcd}(6,a),0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is completely clear for me.

Answer (score 3):

The extensions by $\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}\Z\oplus\Z_6$ of $\Z$ are described by the group $\def\Ext{\operatorname{Ext}}\Ext(\Z\oplus\Z_6,\Z)$. By general theory, this is isomorphic to $\Ext(\Z,\Z)\oplus\Ext(\Z_6,\Z)$. As the first summand is zero, because $\Z$ is free, we need to compute the second group; this can be done by considering the exact sequence
$$
0\to\Z\xrightarrow{\cdot6}\Z\to\Z_6\to0
$$
(where $\cdot6$ denotes “multiplication by $6$) and applying to it the contravariant functor $\def\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom(\Z,-)$:
$$
0\to\Hom(\Z_6,\Z)\to\Hom(\Z,\Z)\xrightarrow{\cdot6}\Hom(\Z,\Z)\to
\Ext(\Z_6,\Z)\to\Ext(\Z,\Z)
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
0\to0\to\Z\xrightarrow{\cdot6}\Z\to\Ext(\Z_6,\Z)\to0
$$
which means that $\Ext(\Z_6,\Z)\cong\Z_6$ and that the isomorphism is exactly the same as the “natural” isomorphism $\Z_6\cong\Hom(\Z_6,\Z_6)$.

In particular there are six non-equivalent extensions of the kind you're looking for. How can you write them?

First, if you're given $0\to\Z\to A\to\Z\oplus\Z_6\to0$, you can say that $\Z$ is a homomorphic image of $A$ and split it off; so $A\cong B\oplus\Z$ and we have an exact sequence $0\to\Z\to B\to\Z_6\to0$. This corresponds to
$$
\Ext(\Z\oplus\Z_6,\Z)\cong\Ext(\Z,\Z)\oplus\Ext(\Z_6,\Z)=0\oplus\Ext(\Z_6,\Z).
$$
Now, let $x\in\Z_6\cong\Hom(\Z_6,\Z_6)$; this corresponds to the endomorphism $\cdot x\colon\Z_6\to\Z_6$ (the multiplication by $x$), so you can consider a pull-back diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \Z @>>> B @>>> \Z_6 @>>> 0 \\
@. @| @VVV @VV{\cdot x}V @. \\
0 @>>> \Z @>{\cdot6}>> \Z @>>> \Z_6 @>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$
It can be proved that, as $x\in\Z_6$, these are the inequivalent extensions, but this would require quite a long argument, that you find in any book dealing with homological algebra.

The “split extension”, $B=\Z\oplus\Z_6$, that is the same as the one you found, corresponds to taking $x=0$.

The pullback $B$ is the subgroup of $\Z\oplus\Z_6$ consisting of the pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a+6\Z=xb$. In the case of $x=0$ it's just $6\Z\oplus\Z_6\cong\Z\oplus\Z_6$. In the case of $x=1$ it is the set of pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a+6\Z=b$. Do the same for the remaining four endomorphisms of $\Z_6$.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but, as a consequence of being not well versed in Homological Algebra (this exercise came up in an Algebraic Topology course), I have not been able to find the groups. Could you help me a bit more, please? Thank you.

Comment: Well, they appear in the comments of Myself and Krish, but I am not able to find the maps for $D_{\infty}$ and $D_{\infty}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{3}$.

Comment: @Gauloises These are the *abelian* extensions: $D_\infty$ is not abelian.

Comment: Ok, thank you. If I am not wrong,B is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ if $x=0$, $\mathbb{Z}$ if $x=1,5$, $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ if $x=2,4$ and $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ if $x=3$. So, there are only 4 abelian groups such that there exist that short exact sequence, isn't it?

Comment: @Gauloises No, they're six.

Answer (score 2):

***Partial Answer:*** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow E \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0$ be an exact sequence of $R$ modules. Then the ***equivalence class of extensions*** is given by ${\rm Ext}^1_{R}(N, M).$ (See any Homological Algebra book.)

In this case $R = \mathbb{Z}, M = \mathbb{Z}, N = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6.$ So need to look at the abelian group ${\rm Ext}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6, \mathbb{Z}).$ First of all, ${\rm Ext}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6, \mathbb{Z}) \cong {\rm Ext}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \oplus{\rm  Ext}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_6, \mathbb{Z}).$ Now ${\rm Ext}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ and ${\rm Ext}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_6, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_6$. (See any Homological Algebra book for this results and how to prove it.)

So we have exactly $6$ non-isomorphic choice for $A$. (But I don't know how to construct them all.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For group extensions in a short exact sequence 
$$0\to A\to E\to B\to 0$$
for **each** of the homomorphisms $B\to{\rm Out}A$ there is an extension $E$.

Also ${\rm Out}\ \Bbb{Z}={\Bbb{Z}}_2$.